# Why multiple data type not possible in single array? - datastructure

Tags: data-structures

I general, I am aware multiple data types in single array typically not allowed in strongly typed language like Java.

I would like to know why technically multiple data type in single array is not possible in terms of data structure (storing in memory location).

Will different datatype hold different bit?. Due to this indexing element will be an problem for multiple data type array?

Comment: You can make an array of object and put whatever you want into it. Usually it’s just not very useful since it’s much more reasonable to store same type of data together. Like I wouldn’t put temperature readings in the same array/list with cooking recipes and family photos. It wouldn’t make sense.

Comment: Storing same type of data together makes more sense. But, I would like to know is there any technical challenges in storing different data type value in contagious memory location and indexing it

Comment: Naturally there is. You need to know the types, sizes etc of every element or otherwise you can’t access them.

Answer (score 0):

All strongly typed languages are produce virtual address space at compile time. Strongly typed languages like C , Java  compiler should know the data time so that it will will create address space. Its all compiler dependent. All assignments, whether explicit or via parameter passing in method calls, are checked for type compatibility. There are no automatic corrections or conversions of conflicting types as in some languages.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

Very good question.

Array generally means you can access any element by index into the array in constant time i.e. O(1).

In C/C++, if you create array of 200, 32-bit integers they are all stored in 
consecutive memory locations.

So if you want to access 10th element you can compute memory address of 10th element as

`base address of the array + 4 * 9` . Then read 32 bytes at that address as your 10th integer. This is what `a[9]` does.

Suppose you allow storage of elements of different types in an array, you won't be able to do this address jumping because different types of items will have different sizes and you won't know what to multiply with.

This breaks the promise that items can be found in O(1).

That is why we don't put items of different types in an array even though its possible. Its definitely possible to do.